# import python FileNotFoundError

Tags: python

I want to read a excel from .py. The code is like:

test2.py

```
import os
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("./test.xlsx")
print(df)
```

However, I want to use the .py file like this:

test1.py

```
from Test import test2
```

And it raises the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './test.xlsx'
```

I have tried:

```
from sys import path 
path.append(...)
```

It doesnt work.
I have searched questions about "import read file python", and I cannot find the answers.
Maybe it is a silly question.However, it really takes me a lot of time.

How to avoid the error without change the test2.py?

Comment: give absolute path of `"./test.xlsx"` instead of relative path.

Comment: give the full path like C:\New Folder\test.xlsx

Comment: I want to avoid the error without change the test2.py

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the directory like this:

```
- __init__.py
- test1.py
- TEST
    - __init__.py
    - test2.xlsx
    - test2.py
```

Using this in test1.py works on my side:

```
import sys
import os

ab_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Test'))
sys.path.append(ab_path)
# Change the directory scope to the import folder
os.chdir(ab_path)
# then you can import test2
import test2
```

Comment: The structure is :Test, test1.py in a folder.And in Test folder, there is test.xlsx and test2.py.And the code above may not work.

Comment: How do you know that the code above will not work? Have you tried it? Why not just have `df = pd.read_excel("Test/test.xlsx")`?

Comment: Yes, I would like you to add the "Test/test.xlsx" after my code above, as suggested by @pavel.

Comment: I have tried it. I dont want to change the test2.py because the code is given by others. And there are a lot of files like test2.py. I think avoiding the error can be implemented.So I raise the question.

Comment: Hi @abcyunice, okay I see your situation now. Having `os.chdir(ab_path)` before you import would allow you to access the Test folder as the working directory, when you import test2. I have edited the solution.

Comment: Welcome. You might want to accept the solution so others could view it too.